# clarification on a question about showing that the closure of a subspace is a subspace

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, measure-theory

In a homework problem, I have been asked to prove the following

"If $X$ is a normed linear space and $S$ is a linear subspace of $X$ then $\overline{S}$ is a linear subspace of $X$." ($\overline{S}$ is the closure of S)

My question is why the assumption that $X$ is a normed linear space is necessary in the first place. Maybe I'm not seeing something. I know that to show that a subset $A$ of $X$ is a subspace it suffices to show that the zero vector is in $A$ and that $A$ is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. Since $\overline{S}$ contains all of the limit points of $S$, I can easily show this by taking sequences in $S$, adding them, multiplying them by scalars, taking limits and showing they're in $\overline{S}$, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limit points are defined through norms. You cannot speak of limits without them, so without them, closure is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption that "$X$ is a normed linear space" is not necessary. This result is valid in an arbitrary  topological linear space(for example, for the linear  space of all real-valued sequences $R^{\infty}$ equipped with product topology which is not normed) for which operations of addition and scalar multiplication are continuous.

Comment: I agree but I think that without metrizability the result is less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

See the first comment to [My proof that the closure of a linear subspace of a topological vector space is again linear.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2920389/my-proof-that-the-closure-of-a-linear-subspace-of-a-topological-vector-space-is).  The bottom line is that the fact that we are dealing with a normed vector space means that the sequences you spoke of are sufficient (since we are dealing with a metric space which in turn means the topology is first-countable).  In a general topological vector space sequences might not be sufficient, so one would need to use nets.