# My proof that the closure of a linear subspace of a topological vector space is again linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space and $Y$ a linear subspace of $X$. The closure of $Y$, say $\overline{Y}$, is also a linear subspace of $X$. To show that, let $x, y \in \overline{Y}$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$. If $ax + by \in \overline{Y}$, then $\overline{Y}$ is a linear subspace. Since $\overline{Y}$ is closure of $Y$, there exist $x_n, y_n \in Y$ such that $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $ax_n + by_n \in Y$ due to the linear subspace $Y$.   And $ax_n + by_n \to ax + by$ due to the continuity of topological vector space $X$. Thus $ax + by \in \overline{Y}$, proved.

Can you check if my proof is correct? Thank you!

Comment: Mostly correct, but your notation suggests $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are sequences, when they should be nets (the topology on $X$ need not be first countable).  Then just build a net that converges to $ax+by$.

Comment: @Aweygan If we talk about topological vector space does it implies that the topology is first countable?